# Secure XOR encryption attempt

Tags: c#, security, encryption, xor

This is my first post and I am very sorry if I made errors with the format.

I am trying to write a program to encrypt all kinds of file via XOR in a secure way. I know that XOR isn't the most secure encryption method but I wanted to give it a try.
So please have a look on my methode and tell me if it is complete bullshit or not :)
The password is a String, chosen by the user.
In the beginning I only XORed the file with the password, leading to an easy decryption if parts of the password were guessed correctly.

Here is my procedure:

1. TmpFile = File XOR (hash of password combined with the pw.length.toString) //to make sure that the password elements are in the right order
2. TmpFile = TmpFile XOR (XOR byte composed by each byte of the password)//ensure that the password to decode has exactly the right chars.
3. TmpFile= TmpFile XOR initial_password

Could the encrypted text be decrypted with the self-XOR-shifting technique?

Thanks for your advice! :)

edit: here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace EncodeEverything
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FileEncrypter v01 \n \n");


                //get password
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your Password (encryption key)");
                string password = getPassword();
                Console.WriteLine("");

            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                //get file to encrypt
                Console.WriteLine("File to encrypt/decrypt:");

                Console.Write("  ");
                string path = Console.ReadLine();

                //-------------------------------
                //load, encrypt & save file
                //-------------------------------
                try {
                    Byte[] tmpBArr = encrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(path), getCustomHash(password));
                    File.WriteAllBytes(path, encrypt(tmpBArr, password));
                    Console.WriteLine("    done.");
                }
                catch(System.Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("!! Error while processing. Path correct? !!");
                }

            }
        }

       private static string getCustomHash(string word)
        {
            string output = "";

            output += word.Length.ToString();
            output += word.GetHashCode();

            return output;
        }

        //encrypt bzw decrypt Byte[]
        public static Byte[] encrypt(byte[] s, string key)
        {
            List<Byte> output = new List<byte>();
            Byte[] codeword = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

            Byte keybyte =(Byte)( codeword[0]^ codeword[0]);
            foreach(Byte b in codeword)
            {
                keybyte = (Byte)(b ^ keybyte);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                output.Add((Byte)(s[i] ^ codeword[i % codeword.Length] ^ keybyte));
            }

            return output.ToArray();
        }



        public static string getPassword()
        {
            Console.Write("  ");

            string pwd = "";
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo i = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                {
                    if (pwd.Length > 0)
                    {
                        pwd= pwd.Remove(pwd.Length - 1);
                        Console.Write("\b \b");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    pwd+=(i.KeyChar);
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }
            return pwd;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a sample code so it becomes more clear question.

Comment: You must specify your algorithm further! You haven't mentioned for example what is done, when your file is larger as the password length. I assume that start again from the beginning (which is the part which makes that insecure). XOR by itself must not be insecure. Consider a Vernam Chiffre (also known as One-Time-Pad): You use a completely random key, that has the same length as the message and XOR that together. If you don't reuse the key ever that is proven to be secure!

Comment: Btw a short disclaimer: Never implement crypto yourself for real world applications that must be secure... It's very easy to get things wrong. Consider the one-time-pad... If you don't get rid of the key material correctly, it could reside in main memory... As you don't have control over the memory layout in C# I assume that is very difficult to be sure that every occurence of the key has been zeroed out in the memory... You could note, that your memory is freed after exit. But consider, that also the OS doesn't zero the memory after exit. With the right tools it's possible to recover it!

Comment: If I follow you correctly, you're implementing a one-time pad. Drop the hash prefix as the only leak and it should work. It should also be secure as long as the pad ("password") is at least as long as the message, genuinely random, and you **never** use that pad again for another message.

Comment: And second disclaimer: I am not a crypto expert, just a computer science student how has heard one or two lectures on this topic. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore this answer if you're just trying to encrypt files as a learning exercise in cryptography, but if you're looking for a real-world solution to securing your file data, read on.

I'd really recommend that you use File encryption built into the .NET framework for this sort of thing if you're looking for a real-world solution to keeping your file data secure.

From Microsoft @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace FileSystemExample
{
    class FileExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string FileName = "test.xml";

                Console.WriteLine("Encrypt " + FileName);

                // Encrypt the file.
                AddEncryption(FileName);

                Console.WriteLine("Decrypt " + FileName);

                // Decrypt the file.
                RemoveEncryption(FileName);

                Console.WriteLine("Done");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        // Encrypt a file.
        public static void AddEncryption(string FileName)
        {

            File.Encrypt(FileName);

        }

        // Decrypt a file.
        public static void RemoveEncryption(string FileName)
        {
            File.Decrypt(FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

It is hard to say for sure that this is what you need, because other things may need to be taken into consideration such as whether you need to pass the file between different clients/servers etc, as well as how much data you're encrypting in each file.

Again, if you're looking for real-world cryptography using C#, I can't stress enough that you should be looking to built-in .NET encryption rather than trying to roll your own- especially if you don't have any formal training in the subject matter. I recommend you pore through Microsoft documentation on .NET framework encryption if you're interested in securing data in production:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ss79b2x(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a nice walkthrough for creating an example file encrypting windows form application:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397867(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dislike this answer, which proposes an encryption without an configurable key :-/ I assume that Microsoft stores it somewhere together with the user profile on disk... But from my point of view, you can also use the normal file permissions of the operating system to keep other users of the system away... You didn't get anything by using this, even worse I am not sure If there is really no secret way for the admin of the machine to encrypt the file...

Comment: @flammi88 that's a fair cop. However, the OP was not terribly specific with his requirements other than "I want to encrypt some files". I just wanted to put this up there in case he was seriously trying to implement his own cryptography for real-world use, and to point him in the direction of using the .NET Framework's built in cryptography. I will update my post to include other  .NET encryption options.

Comment: Using the .net crypto API without producing security holes is almost as hard as writing it from scratch. I can count the secure implementations I've seen over the years on one hand. For example, your last link is not secure under chosen ciphertext attacks.

Answer (score 3):

1. `string.GetHashCode` doesn't have a well defined return value. So you might not even be able to decrypt the file after you restart the process.
2. Your key consists of a 32 bit value plus the length of the password. Brute-forced in seconds on a single computer.
3. Once the file is longer than the hashed key, the key starts repeating, you get a many-time-pad. So even if we ignored the brute-force attack, it'd still be easy to break. It's essentially a xor based vigenere variant.
4. Ignoring the xor-ed parity byte, which is the same for each byte in the message, the key-stream bytes are ASCII digits, so each key byte has at best 3.3 bits of entropy. Comparing this with the approximately 1.5 bits of entropy per letter in English text, shows you that it's quite weak, even without key-stream repetitions.

=> it's buggy and insecure

Comment: A couple of days ago we had a user who didn't know the code and didn't even recognize `xor` break encryption equivalent to yours: [Encryption used in a commercial software product](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31836/encryption-used-in-a-commercial-software-product)